# TypeError: coercing to Unicode when run thru Windows CMD

Tags: python, file

Hello i have next error in my script when running thru CMD,  but it succesfully works in MVS debuger.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Work\PyLineCounter\PyLineCounter\PyLineCounter\PyLineCounter.py", line 22, in <module>
    file = open(file_path,'rb')
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, WindowsPath found
```

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# coding=utf-8

import re
import os
import io
import sys
import codecs
import chardet
import time

from pathlib import Path

PATH = "d:/work/"
strings_counter = 0

for file_path in Path(PATH).rglob('*.h'):

    file = open(file_path,'rb')
    raw_data = file.read()
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a Python version that doesn't yet support using `pathlib` path objects in the `open()` function call. You can only do that [as of Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-519-adding-a-file-system-path-protocol) and up.

You can:

- Upgrade to Python 3.6 or newer
- Convert the path to a string yourself with `str()`, so `open(str(file_path), 'rb')`.
- Use the [`Path.open()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.open) instead of the `open()` function.
- Use the [`Path.read_binary()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_bytes) instead of manually opening and reading the data.

That last option is easily the cleanest here, as it lets you remove two lines of code:

```
for file_path in Path(PATH).rglob('*.h'):
    raw_data = file_path.read_bytes()
```

However, this does require Python 3.5 or newer. That's already quite an old version and [only receives security fixes now](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-358rc2/). If you are using Python 3.4, you *really* want to upgrade, as that version is no longer receiving any support.

But should you be stuck with Python 3.4, then use `Path.open()`:

```
for file_path in Path(PATH).rglob('*.h'):
    with file_path.open('rb'):
        raw_data = file_path.read_bytes()
```

Note that your use of `file = open(...)`, *do something with `file`*, `file.close()`  is better handled by using the file as a context manager, so `with open(...) as file:`, (new indent level), *do something with `file`*, and leave it to the `with` statement to close the file object for you. I used that pattern in my `Path.open()` example above.

Comment: Thank you for complete answer. But conversion to str doesnt works in my cas.